# Syntax Error on document.ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am gettig a Syntax Error when executing `$(document).ready(ev => { ... });`. 
I am getting the Error at the greater than(**>**) symbole.
Does anyone know how to solve this? Or is this just a IE fail.

Pic:
[Picture of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n5ON.png)

Comment: IE has no support for arrow functions (ie. the `=>` syntax). Use traditional anonymous function definitions instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks! I did not know that.